# In Windows Phone 8, SQLite works but doesn't write the database file to IsoStore

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

My app is using `sqlite-net-wp8` for Windows Phone 8 to manage a local database.

It seems that the database file is never written to IsoStore (as seen with `IsoStoreSpy`).
No exceptions are thrown.

I have tried the following:

- Upgrading SQLite for Windows Phone from 3.7.1.16 to 3.8.0.2 (an extremely painful process)
- Providing absolute and relative paths as suggested in [Working with sqlite in windows phone 8 a sqlite net version for mobile](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/).

  ```
  SQLite.SqliteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename))
  SQLite.SqliteConnection(filename)
  ```
- Providing SQLiteOpenFlags explicitly to the SQLite.SQLiteConnection
- Other random things

Here is my code (I am using `USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE`)

```
string filename = "data.db";
string seqStr = "CREATE TABLE ...";
using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(filename, 
    SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite, true))
{
    db.BeginTransaction();
    db.Execute(seqStr);
    db.Commit();
    db.Close();
}
```

I have run out of ideas. If someone can help me, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Any reason why you are `Close()`ing the database connection yourself? Shouldn't the `using` do that for you?

Comment: Hi I have a doubt, what ever the db may be, sql lite or something else, In windows phone the files will save in isolated storage only, right? or if the files save in some other place where it would be.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, solved!

You are right, `db.Close()` is redundant (the Dispose will call the Close() function.

My non-working code:

```
string filename = "Data Source=" + "data.db" + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
```

My now working code:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "data.db");
```

One small roadblock removed, many more to go!